# PHP strtotime excludes New Year's Day... How to include the holiday?

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

It looks like PHP's strtotime function is excluding New's Year Day from its results. Is there a way to force strtotime to include it? Other holidays such as Labor Day do not seem to have this problem (see the 3rd code example below).

Thanks!

```
// The 1st Wed in Jan 2020 falls on New Year's Day
// But we get: "Wed 2020-01-08" (INCORRECT... it should return "Wed 2020-01-01")
echo date("D Y-m-d", strtotime("First Wednesday " . "2020-01"));

// However, asking for the 1st Thu in Jan 2020 returns the correct result: "Thu 2020-01-02"
echo date("D Y-m-d", strtotime("First Thursday " . "2020-01"));

// Even asking for the 1st Mon in Sep 2020, which is Labor Day returns the correct result: "Mon 2020-09-07"
echo date("D Y-m-d", strtotime("First Monday " . "2020-09"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `"First Wednesday of 2020-01"` instead (note the `of`).

Per [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

> Observe the following remarks when the current day-of-week is the same
> as the day-of-week used in the date/time string:
>
> [...]
>
> "ordinal dayname" **does advance to another day**. (Example "first wednesday july 23rd, 2008" means "2008-07-30").
>
> [...]
>
> "ordinal dayname 'of' " **does not advance to another day**. (Example: "first tuesday of july 2008" means "2008-07-01").

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed that in the docs. Still seems strange that Jan 01 gets special treatment when not using the "of", but i'll take it! Thanks again.

Comment: @bjones1831 That's because the first of january was a wednesday this year (2020). Basically it's like saying "first wednesday *after* Jan 1 2020", as opposed to "first wednesday *including* Jan 1 2020". Hence why it's different only when the specified day of week (left part) is exactly equal to that of the referenced day (right part).

Comment: Gotcha. And I just tested the holiday of May Day (May 1st), and it had the same error without the "of".... Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
echo date("D Y-m-d", strtotime("First Wednesday of January 2020"));
// Wed 2020-01-01
```